# Why to pass a template parameter in Qt method

Tags: qt, casting

I'm trying to read some example code about implicit creation of QVariants from enum values.
About the following line of code:

```
QVariant::fromValue<Qt::PenStyle>(Qt::SolidLine)
```

I don't really understand what is the purpose of **Qt::PenStyle** in the above expression.
I think Qt::SolidLine is unique. 
The syntax is OK?
Shouldn't it be something like:

```
QVariant::fromValue(Qt::SolidLine)
```

?
Sorry if this question seems dumb.

Comment: `Qt::PenStyle` is a type (enum), and `Qt::SolidLine` is a value of that type.

Comment: [Function template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this form:

```
1) QVariant::fromValue(Qt::SolidLine)
```

`QVariant::fromValue(const T & value)` is a [template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) method. When you call a template method or function you can specify for what type of argument this method should be called. If you don't do that a compiler tries to do it for you. That is why 1) is equal to this:

```
2) QVariant::fromValue<Qt::PenStyle>(Qt::SolidLine)
```

But you can call this method for `int` and pass `enum value` (*if you are not at c++11*):

```
3) QVariant::fromValue<int>(Qt::SolidLine)
```

or even force creating of `QPen`:

```
4) QVariant::fromValue<QPen>(Qt::SolidLine)
```

EDIT:
If someone is suprised by 4 and want to know how it works:  it is the same as if there was a method (actually it is created during the compilation):

```
QVariant::fromValue(const QPen& pen);
```

When you call this method with `Qt::SolidLine` compiler uses an implicit constructor `QPen(Qt::PenStyle style)` to create a new temporary `QPen` object and pass it as an argument to the method `fromValue`.